# Error: Undefined variable json

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

### Get states by Country

I created three option box to selecting area, state and Country. The problem is country working well however when I want to get city and area that gives me error undefined variable in other scripts which I used that is worked.

Undefined variable: country_id

### Controller

```
public function get_city()
{   
    $this->load->model('cities_model');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $country_id = $country_id?$country_id:$this->input->post('country_id');
    if($country_id) 
    echo json_encode($this->cities_model->get_city());
}
```

### Model

```
public function get_city($country_id = 0){
    return 
    $this->db->select('name as text, city_id as value')
            ->where('country_id', $country_id)
            ->get('cities')
            ->result();
 }
```

### View

```
<li>
                            <label class="form-label required">Country</label>
                            <div class="form-item">
                                <select class="selectpicker" name="country_id" data-url="/admin/events/get_countries" data-select="city-1" data-select-group="1" required></select>
                            </div>
                        </li>   
                        <li class="hide" data-select-group="1" data-select-sub="city-1">
                            <label class="form-label required">City</label>
                            <div class="form-item">
                                <select class="selectpicker" name="city_id" data-url="/admin/events/get_city" data-select="area-1" required></select>
                            </div>
                        </li>                                    
                        <li class="hide" data-select-group="1" data-select-sub="area-1">
                            <label class="form-label required">Area</label>
                            <div class="form-item area_id">
                                <select class="selectpicker" name="area_id" data-url="/admin/events/get_area" required></select>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Comment: Not sure if there's more to the function in the controller you didn't post, but the error seems pretty clear: you test for a variable $country_id before you define it.

Comment: use isset($country_id) to check if the variable has been set before you're using it.

Comment: Could we see the form tag?  Also, you aren't passing the country_id to the model function get_cities.  Another thing...$country_id variable isn't initialized anywhere.  So your iif statement is likely confused.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me this should be sufficient:

```
public function get_city()
{   
    $this->load->model('cities_model');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $country_id = $this->input->post('country_id');
    if(isset($country_id) && $country_id) {
        echo json_encode($this->cities_model->get_city());
    }
}
```

Comment: same mistake undefined

Comment: Where is the error coming from, the controller or the model? I don't think it's causing your error, but shouldn't you be passing $country_id to `$this->cities_model->get_city()`?

Comment: that comes from controller

Comment: From which line in the controller? I made an edit because I was missing a brace, but there shouldn't be any way that code generates an undefined variable error in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller try this

$country_id = $this->load->model('cities_model',$country_id);

Comment: same mistake undefined

Answer (score 0):

try this

$id = $this->input->post('country_id')

$country_id = $this->load->model('cities_model',$id);

Comment: unexpected country id

Comment: can you check your post with this

 print_r($this->input->post('country_id'))